# Android SharedPrefences multiple values for one key

Tags: android, arrays, string, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I have a probleme here.

I don't know how to read all values of a SharedPreferences for one particular key.
Actually I'm trying to write an Arraylist in preferences , then read it.

Let me explain with some code, Here is my methods for write in preferences :

```
fun writeArrayOnPreferences(key: String?, array: ArrayList<String>, c:Context) {
        val preferences = c.getSharedPreferences(
                c.getString(key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        with(preferences.edit()) {
            for (value in array) {
                putString(key, value)
            }
            commit()
        }
    }
```

My writing code works , it's persistent , but I don't really understand how to READ this Arraylist from preferences.

I tried a lot of things to read this but it show me only the last element wrote in preferences

I really want you to understand that I want multiple values for a specific key

Comment: I said hello guys but stackOverflow deleted it , so Hello :)

Comment: Heyho :) `SharedPreferences` doesn't keep multiple values for a key. `putString(key, value)` with the same key will replace the previous value. That's why it only shows the last key.

To use the same key, all `String` values have to be added up to one `String` and that can be saved with the key. The answers show ways to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a quick example based on **Nabin Bhandari**'s answer

```
fun writeArrayOnPreferences(key: String, array: ArrayList<String>, c:Context) {
    val jsonString = Gson().toJson(array)
    pref.edit().putString(key, jsonString).commit()
}

fun readArrayFromPreferences(key: String, c: Context): ArrayList<String> {
    val jsonString = pref.getString(key)
    val array = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, ArrayList<String>()::class.java)
    return array
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this very nice example ! The "ArrayList<String>()::class.java)" part helped me so much because I was lost

Answer (score 3):

ok here how it is! If you want multiple data against one key in share pref editor then  **SET** is your solution as After API 11 the SharedPreferences Editor accept Sets. You could convert your List into a HashSet or something similar and store it like that When your read it back, convert it into an ArrayList, sort it if needed and you're good to go.

```
        //Set the values
        val yourSet = HashSet<String>()
        set.addAll(listOfExistingScores)
        yourPrefEditor.putStringSet("key", yourSet)
        yourPrefEditor.commit()

        //Retrieve the values
        val yourSet = yourPref.getStringSet("key", null)
```

**SOLUTION NUMBER 2**

would be like serializing the ArrayList and passing it! but there can be a catch if any value in your array does posses any rule that can't be Parced it will **crash**!

For More check this [**Thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences) this is in java but it will help tell you more!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply loop values in an `ArrayList` put them in the preferences using same key for all values and expect to retrieve the `ArrayList` back.

You can convert the 'ArrayList' in `JSON` format and store it in `SharedPreferences`. Then to parse the `JSON` string to get the `ArrayList`.

You can make this process easier with the help of a library called `Gson`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    with(preferences.edit()) {
        var s = "" 
        for (value in array) {
            s = s + value + ","
        }
        putString(key, value)
        commit()
    }
```

your array will be saved like comma separated values which when read back in a string, by using the split function will become an array.